# cmd, find .exe with version number

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, cygwin

I have a folder with a lot of folders and executables, I would like to get a list of executables and their version numbers.

I have a couple of things to my disposal:

```
Anything on windows 7
Cygwin
C#
```

Example

```
\folder\temp.exe
\folder\folder2\temp2.exe
\folder\folder3\temp3.exe
```

I would like my results to be

```
temp.exe  Version 1.0.1.2
temp2.exe Version 4.45.6.7
temp3.exe Version 1.0.0.0
```

Currently I an using this command to get me the list of .exe but I can't seem to get the version numbers.

```
dir c:\temp\ /s | find ".exe"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to get to only exe files in a specific directory and get to the version information:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var files = di.GetFiles("*.exe");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        var version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(file.FullName).FileVersion;
        Console.WriteLine($"{file.Name} Version {version}");
    }
}
```